# How to fix GNUPLOT replot issue

Tags: gnuplot

I set-up a multiplot like this:

```
set terminal wxt size 1500,900
set format x "%d%m%y %H:%M:%S"
set xdata time
set timefmt x "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"
set key font ",6"
set lmargin 10
set rmargin 10
set multiplot layout 2,1
plot "output.txt" u 1:2 w lines axes x1y1, \
"output.txt" u 1:3 w lines axes x1y2
plot "output.txt" u 1:40 w lines axes x1y1, \
"output.txt" u 1:39 w lines axes x1y2
set y2tics border
unset multiplot
```

Which works, and gives me 2 plots, one above the other.

But pressing the "replot" button (or using zoom) causes the second plot to fill the window - completely hiding the first plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's how `replot` behaves. The documentation says: „Note that in multiplot mode, replot can only reproduce the most recent component plot, not the full set.“.

So, what you can do is to put the whole `set multiplot ... unset multiplot` stuff in an external file, `load` it, and then `load` it again. Or put that stuff in a string and `eval` it several times.

Comment: Hmm, that's painful! I am trying to zoom in - the external load is not really going to work.

Comment: You are right, thats not really going to work for your case. But it is very unlikely, that this feature will appear in the near future (don't ask me about the time span :).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another workaround. It does not answer the question directly, but it could give idea to other similar issues. Put header, and a footer 'reread', then two context could be choosen for a similar multiplot (done twice)

```
if (exists("rehearse")) rehearse=1+rehearse; set term x11
if (!exists("rehearse")) rehearse=0; set term png; set output sprintf("test_palette_%s.png", system("date +\"%F\""))

pr "rehearse=".rehearse; show term #<= comment printing
set samples 100;  set isosample 100,100
set xrange [0:1]; set yrange [0:1]
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "red")
set autoscale cbfix; unset colorbox; unset key

set multiplot layout 2,2   
plot '++' using 1:2:1 with image
plot '++' using 1:2:2 with image
plot '++' using 1:2:(-$1) with image
plot '++' using 1:2:(-$2) with image
unset multiplot

if(rehearse <  1) reread
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Solved it with a loop:

```html
set term wxt enh

do for [IDX = 0:1] {

  if (IDX==1) {
    set terminal png enhanced
    set output 'temp.png'
  }

  set multiplot

  set size 1,1
  set origin 0,0
  plot sin(x)

  set size 0.5,0.35
  set origin 0.13,0.63
  plot cos(x)

  unset multiplot
}

set output
set term wxt enh
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with question. It doesn't solve the `replot` issue, which the OP asked about.